# How to share a component to 2 child module from the parent module?

Tags: angular, angular9

I have a shared component, I am trying to import them in to my feature module. But getting error. not able to import. i am export as well. only thing is it's just component not an module.

here is my code :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FeatureOneModule } from './feature1/feature-one.module';
import { FeatureTwoModule } from './feature2/feature-two.module';
import { ScopeRoutesModule } from './setup-config.routes';
import { SetupConfig } from "./setup-config.component";
import { SharedOne } from "./../shared-component/shared-one.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations:[SetupConfig, SharedOne],
  imports:      [ 
    FormsModule,
    ScopeRoutesModule,
    FeatureOneModule,
    FeatureTwoModule ],
  exports:[RouterModule, SharedOne]
})
export class ScopeModule { }
```

in the above i am trying for "SharedOne" to used under "FeatureOneModule" and "FeatureTwoModule". any one help me here?[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scope-router)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Angular's style guide, you should create a [`SharedModule`](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module) to contain all components / pipes etc shared across multiple feature modules.
In each feature module you need those shared components, import `SharedModule`.

Also, it seems that you didn't include `FeatureOneDelete` and `FeatureOneEdit` in `FeatureOneModule` declarations.

I have forked your stackblitz and edited it, explore the source code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scope-router-ksdrzh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsetup-config%2Ffeature1%2Ffeature-one.module.ts).